# How can I insert data into Database Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to programming. I have created a basic form inside views/register.blade.php like this

```
         @section('content')
<h1>Registration Form</h1><hr>
<h3>Please insert the informations bellow:</h3>
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'test/register','method'=>'post'))}}
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"><br><br>
<input type="password" placeholder="password"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="REGISTER NOW!">
{{Form::close()}}@stop
```

I have a controller. like this

```
         public function create()
         {
             $user= Input::all();
               $user = new User;
               $user->username = Input::get('username');
               $user->email = Input::get('email');
               $user->password = Input::get('password');
               $user->save();

            return Redirect::back();
        }
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('test/register', array('uses'=>'TestController@create'))
```

I can not register users through the form. Would you please suggest me how to do that?

Comment: What is your question? What's happening? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Make sure your `User` model is set up correctly. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

Comment: Is it creating a record? Looking from here it should, you have a small bug, but it will not interfere.

Comment: I have just edited my question. There are too many errors are being shown to me. @AntonioCarlosRibeiro

Comment: No it is not creating any record.

Comment: So you have to show them to us, not seeing those errors is diffucult to understand what is going on your end.

Comment: Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException and note that I have users table into my schema.

Comment: Always start debugging your errors by the error message, in 90% of the time it will tell you exactly what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error MethodNotAllowedHttpException means the route exists, but the HTTP method (GET) is wrong. You have to change it to POST:

```
Route::post('test/register', array('uses'=>'TestController@create'));
```

Also, you need to hash your passwords:

```
public function create()
{
    $user = new User;

    $user->username = Input::get('username');
    $user->email = Input::get('email');
    $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    $user->save();

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

And I removed the line:

```
$user= Input::all();
```

Because in the next command you replace its contents with

```
$user = new User;
```

To debug your Input, you can, in the first line of your controller:

```
dd( Input::all() );
```

It will display all fields in the input.

Comment: I have done this. Still it has an error. The error is : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'password' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users` (`username`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (sss, atik@gmail.com, , 2014-09-26 19:43:23, 2014-09-26 19:43:23))

Comment: Now you have a different problem, your password field is empty!

Comment: Yes. But I inserted my password. Why does it show empty?

Comment: Alright. It works. I am familiar with core php. I did basic authentication, so I tried not to Hash the password at all. Thanks for the solution. I owe you . :)

Comment: Nice. No problem, mate.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you use the **POST** to insert the data. Actually you were using **GET**.

Answer (score 0):

First method you can try this

```
$department->department_name = $request->department_name;
$department->status = $request->status;
$department->save();
```

Another way to insert records into the database with create function

```
$department = new Department;           
// Another Way to insert records
$department->create($request->all());

return redirect('admin/departments');
```

You need to set the filledby in Department model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Department extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['department_name','status'];
}
```

Comment: From creating new migration to creating form and then inserting record in database, with sample code and output http://www.devtrainings.com/2016/05/laravel-eloquent-insert-row-or-add.html