# I am new in Laravel can any one tell how can i save number in a table and square of that number into another table using helper?

Tags: laravel

Actually I am new in Laravel can anyone tell me how I can save a number in a table and the square of that number into another table using helper?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: do u know the solution

Comment: have no idea of helpers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I insert data into Database Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067065/how-can-i-insert-data-into-database-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample:

```
$value = 4;
DB::table('table_name')->insert(['column_name' => $value]);

$sqrt_value = sqrt($value);
DB::table('table_name')->insert(['column_name' => $sqrt_value]);
```

Also you can read documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#inserts).

Comment: but i have to do it using helper

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers - helpers have nothing to insert into table. Why you want only with helper?

Comment: i was asked to do so

Comment: I think you can ask your boss one more time, if it should be done only using helper.