# Pass JSON data from JavaScript in view to controller in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a web application where I fetch JSON data from a database table, edit it, and want to ultimately insert it back into the database.

**tree.blade.php**

```
@extends ('layout')

@section ('content')
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- echo JSON data from model to js variable -->
    <script type="text/javascript"> var treeData = <?php echo $family->family_tree ?>; </script>

    <!-- main js file where treeData is edited -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>

  </body>
</html>
@endsection
```

**Family.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Family extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'families';
}
```

**FamiliesController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use DB;
use App\Family;

//fetch first row from table and pass it to view
class FamiliesController extends Controller {
  public function showTree() {
      $family = Family::where('id', 1)->firstOrFail();

      return view('tree', [
        'family' => $family
      ]);
  }
}

?>
```

**web.php**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/tree', 'FamiliesController@showTree');
?>
```

**So my question is**: how can I pass the JSON data from `treeData` to the controller, and then to update the value in the database table? Is there a 'best practice' in doing this?

While googling for solutions I found mainly two ways:

1. Sending the data with **AJAX** using `XMLHttpRequest`, but I found that it needs a link to a php file in which the data is received. But how would that work with laravel structure?
2. Using an HTML form and a `Route::post(..);` but apparently laravel v7 doesn't support the Form class...

Comment: "_a link to a php file_" A controller-action in Laravel basically is a PHP file. Create a route to send to. "_but apparently laravel v7 doesn't support the Form class_" What?

Comment: 1. I'm sorry, what do you mean by "A controller-action in Laravel basically is a PHP file"? could you elaborate please?
2. If I try to do something like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067065/how-can-i-insert-data-into-database-laravel
I get the error: "class 'Form' not found..."

Comment: 1. Ajax doesn't need to be sent to "_a php file_" as you stated. Ajax can send to Laravel routes too 2. That's a specific 3rd party Form class (from LaravelCollective I think). You can of course still create your own standard HTML forms in Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple XHR request using Axios would do it:

```
axios.post('/your-route-that-will-handle-the-data', {
  data: {
    json_var // you json data goes here
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
})
.then(function () {
  // always executed
});
```

Now [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) use XmlHTTPrequest under the hood, and i would recommend for its easy to use syntax